# How to call Firebase JS method using AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am using [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md) (Interfacing library between [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) and AngularJS).

I would like to call the javascript method [sendEmailVerification()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification) in my angular code. When I implement the below code, I get an error saying that: `$scope.authObj.sendEmailVerification is not a function.` which is probably because I am trying to use javascript method in AngularJS (AngularFire).

Is there a way to use Javascript methods by using AngularFire ?

```
$scope.signUp = function() {

  $scope.authObj.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {

      $scope.sendVerifyEmail();

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
}

$scope.sendVerifyEmail = function(){
  $scope.authObj.sendEmailVerification();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that I could write a javascript function outside app.controller with the required Firebase methods and call it from inside app.controller i.e. inside Angular methods.

Below is my updated code

```
// The below JS function written outside app.controller
function sendVerifyEmail(firebaseUser){
  firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
}
```

The above JS function is called from the below angular function

```
$scope.signUp = function() {

  $scope.authObj.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
    .then(function(firebaseUser) {

      sendVerifyEmail(firebaseUser);

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: ", error);
    });
}
```